# Cause vs make / get

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

Which one is idiomatic or is there another way to say it in more idiomatic and a bit formal way?

> What I read caused a question to pop up in my mind?
>
> What I read caused  to pop up a question in my mind?
>
> what I read made /got a question pop up in my mind ?

Comment: Hint: "pop up" is very colloquial, so if you want something more formal, replace it. A suggestion would be "raised a (new / additional) question". "in my mind" is not neccessary because the reading - or rather understanding what you read - happens in your mind already.

Comment: @Stephie thank you for your answer.Do you think I should replace "pop up" with " raise" or I should use "raise" without "cause or make" to prevent overwording.

Comment: @Stephie Do you think my sentences sound natural and correct ?

Comment: "Raised a question", not "caused a qu. to r**i**se"! Keep it short

Comment: Am.Eng. All are statements, not questions. 1) Fine. 2) very awkward-sounding, 3) made: ok, got: not ok.

Comment: @mkennedy: thanks for catching the "?", I had clearly missed this. Oh, and OP asked for "a bit formal" - what's your thought on "pop up"?

Comment: @Stephie thanks for catching the idiomatic/formal. "pop up" is already very idiomatic so perhaps OP means less idiomatic way? More formal could be, "What I read caused a further question: blah, blah?" Or Reading the passage gave rise to this question: blah, blah?"

Comment: @mkennedy: Shoudn't one of us put all these comments into an answer?

Comment: @Stephie Go ahead!

Answer (score 1):

The first one is idiomatic. To be more formal (as @Stephie pointed out) you could drop the colloquial "pop up". So you could try:

> What I read raised a question in my mind

or, to avoid that clumsy alliteration on "r" in "read raised", and providing the surrounding context supports it, you could have:

> The material raised a question in my mind

Also, stating that the question was in your mind is a bit redundant (where else would it be, in your leg? :-) ). Hence:

> The material raised a question for me